# postfix: timing of client responses in a milter and in after-queue processing?

Tags: smtp, postfix-mta, milter

I'm currently using postfix-2.11.3, and I am doing a lot of message processing through a milter. This processing takes place before the client is notified that the message is accepted, and it sometimes involves enough work that it delays the client's receipt of the initial SMTP `250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as xxxxxxxxxxx` message.

During large email blasts to my server, this milter processing can cause a backlog, and in some cases, the client connections time out while waiting for that initial `250 ...` message.

My question is this: if I rewrite my milter as a postfix after-queue filter with no before-queue processing, will clients indeed get the initial `250` messages right away, with perhaps subsequent SMTP messages coming later? Or will the `250` message still be deferred until after postfix completes the after-queue filtering?

And is it possible for an initial `250` message to be received by the client with a subsequent `4xx` or `5xx` message received and processed later by that same client, in case the after-queue filter decides to subsequently reject the message?

I know I could test this by writing an after-queue filter. However, my email server is busy, and I don't have a test server available, and so I'd like to know in advance whether an after-queue filter can behave in this manner.

Thank you for any wisdom you could share about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to set up a postfix instance on a test machine, and I was able to install a dummy after-queue filter. This allowed me to figure out the answer to my question. It turns out that postfix indeed sends the `250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as xxxxxxxxxxx` message before the after-queue filter completes.

This means that I can indeed move my slower milter processing to the after-queue filter in order give senders a quicker SMTP response.